# Power BI Embedded - Filtering not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-rest-api

I am trying to embed a Power BI report into my Laravel project using the Power BI REST API. The report is loading successfully. However, I am facing issues with applying filters to the report, specifically using a column named 'Partner Name' from the Excel dataset as a filter. I am also including my library's importing code.

```
<head>
<script src="https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/node_modules/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/powerbi-client/2.22.4/powerbi.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/powerbi-client/2.22.4/powerbi.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/powerbi-models@1.12.6/dist/models.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/powerbi-models@1.12.6/dist/models.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="embedContainer"></div>
<script>

    let loadedResolve, reportLoaded = new Promise((res, rej) => { loadedResolve = res; });
    let renderedResolve, reportRendered = new Promise((res, rej) => { renderedResolve = res; });
    const tokenType = '0';
    let report;
    const models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

    async function embedPowerBIReport() {
        let accessToken = 'eyKoxxxUxIx3RNLWzQ';
        let embedUrl = 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=4ef9a267-68f5-49ff-b292-6a53195f67 a267asdflyZWN0LmFuYWx5c2lzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0IiwiZW1iZWRGZWF0dXJlcyI6eyJtb2Rlcm5FbWJlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXNhZ2VNZXRyaWNzVk5leHQiOnRydWV9fQ%3d%3d';
        let embedReportId = '4ef9a267-68f5-49ff-b292-6a53195f671f';

        const config = {
            type: 'report',
            tokenType: tokenType == '0' ? models.TokenType.Aad : models.TokenType.Embed,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            embedUrl: embedUrl,
            id: embedReportId,
            permissions: models.Permissions.All,
            settings: {
                filterPaneEnabled: true,
                navContentPaneEnabled: true
            }
        };

        let embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

        report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

        report.off("loaded");

        report.on("loaded", function () {
            loadedResolve();
            report.off("loaded");
        });

        report.off("error");

        report.on("error", function (event) {
            console.log(event.detail);
        });

        report.off("rendered");

        report.on("rendered", function () {
            renderedResolve();
            report.off("rendered");
        });

       
    }

     embedPowerBIReport();

        const filter2 = {
            $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
            target: {
                table: "WBL-AllReviews-Export Less Records.csv",
                column: "Partner name"
            },
            operator: "In",
            values: ["WBL-Test"]
        };

    async function fn3() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            report.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Add, [filter2])
        })
    }

    async function fn() {
        try {
            const res1 = await reportLoaded
            console.log('reportLoaded：' + res1)
            const res2 = await reportRendered
            console.log('reportRendered：' + res2)
            const res3 = await fn3()
            console.log('fn3()：' + res3)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error)
        }
    }
    fn()
    

</script>
```

The above code cause errors like,

reportLoaded：undefined
powerbi:131 reportRendered：undefined
powerbi:133 fn3()：undefined

I also tried a different approach using the following code snippet:
This code doesn't cause any errors but the filtering part is not working.

```
<script>
        let loadedResolve, reportLoaded = new Promise((res, rej) => { loadedResolve = res; });
        let renderedResolve, reportRendered = new Promise((res, rej) => { renderedResolve = res; });
        let report;
        const models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

        function embedPowerBIReport() {
            const accessToken = 'eyJeXAiOxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            const embedUrl = 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=4efxxxxxxx-xxxxxd%3dd%3d';
            const embedReportId = '4efxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

            const tokenType = '0';

            const permissions = models.Permissions.All;

            const config = {
                type: 'report',
                tokenType: tokenType == '0' ? models.TokenType.Aad : models.TokenType.Embed,
                accessToken: accessToken,
                embedUrl: embedUrl,
                id: embedReportId,
                permissions: permissions,
                settings: {
                    panes: {
                        filters: {
                            visible: true
                        },
                        pageNavigation: {
                            visible: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            const embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

             report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

            report.off("loaded");
            report.on("loaded", function () {
                loadedResolve();
                report.off("loaded");
            });

            report.off("error");
            report.on("error", function (event) {
                console.log(event.detail);
            });

            report.off("rendered");
            report.on("rendered", function () {
                renderedResolve();
                report.off("rendered");
            });
        }
        async function applyFilter() {
            alert("dsfa");
            const filter = {
                $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
                target: {
                    table: "WBL-AllReviews-Export Less Records.csv",
                    column: "Partner name"
                },
                operator: "In",
                values: ["WBL-Test"]
            };

            await reportLoaded;
            await reportRendered;

            report.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Add, [filter]);
        }
        embedPowerBIReport();

        try {
            setTimeout(applyFilter);
            console.log("Report filter was added.");
        }
        catch (errors) {
            console.log(errors);
        }
</script>
```

**Expected Behavior**: I expect the Power BI report to filter data based on the 'Partner Name' column when the report is loaded.

**Actual Behavior**: The report loads successfully, but the filtering is not applied as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if table name parameter you are passing is correct? There shouldn't be .csv file extension in parameter. Verify table name in Power BI Service and pass the same name as the parameter.

[image]

**Before filtering:**

[image]

**After filtering:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Madhav, thanks. This solution worked for me. Please can you tell me whether is there any way I can apply multiple filters my first filter would be 'Partner' and the second would be 'Project' and both of these columns are in two Excel sheets that are used for a dataset.